# Suggested edit links on the wrong revisions in the revision history

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, revisions-list

There is something wrong with the revision history for [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/79173/revisions).  It's a question that I made two consecutive edit suggestions (both approved) on when I was sub-2k.

However, the link to the suggested edit page for the 4th revision (my first suggestion) is placed on the 3rd revision (the OP's edit).  Clicking on it still goes to the right suggested edit page, it's just not placed where it should be.

[image: oops]

I'm not sure if this has occurred anywhere else or just on this one but it should be fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the result of a bug that was fixed shortly afterwards (on February 24, to be precise), causing a mismatch between the suggested edit and the revision it created. That data will be fixed up with the next database migration; after that, the link will be on the correct revision.

Nice catch, thanks.